# How to use str.replace in Python 3

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to replace patterns by strings in a column of my dataframe. In Python 2 this works fine.

```
df = df['Transaction Description'].str.replace("apple", "pear")
```

But in Python 3 it gives me:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-1f1e7cb2faf3> in <module>()
----> 1 df = df['Transaction Description'].str.replace("apple", "pear")

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in replace(self, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)
   2427     def replace(self, pat, repl, n=-1, case=None, flags=0, regex=True):
   2428         result = str_replace(self._data, pat, repl, n=n, case=case,
-> 2429                              flags=flags, regex=regex)
   2430         return self._wrap_result(result)
   2431 

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py in str_replace(arr, pat, repl, n, case, flags, regex)
    637         raise TypeError("repl must be a string or callable")
    638 
--> 639     is_compiled_re = is_re(pat)
    640     if regex:
    641         if is_compiled_re:

~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/inference.py in is_re(obj)
    217     """
    218 
--> 219     return isinstance(obj, re_type)
    220 
    221 

/usr/lib/python3.5/typing.py in __instancecheck__(self, obj)
    258 
    259     def __instancecheck__(self, obj):
--> 260         raise TypeError("Type aliases cannot be used with isinstance().")
    261 
    262     def __subclasscheck__(self, cls):

TypeError: Type aliases cannot be used with isinstance().
```

> What's the right way to do this in python 3?

I am using pandas 0.23.0 in both cases.

Comment: Are you sure this is a Python issue? `pd.Series.str.replace` is a Pandas API method, not a pure Python function. Therefore, it may help if you give us your Pandas version in each instance instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That's a bug in Python 3.5.2 and lower

What is your python version?

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495099/typeerror-type-aliases-cannot-be-used-with-isinstance?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

> 0.23.1 saved the day
>   @Anush

Note:
You should have first searched google for *"TypeError: Type aliases cannot be used with isinstance()"* and you would have arrived at the answer immediately

Comment: Oh it's 3.5.2. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @Anush I believe pandas 0.23.1 has just been released which probably has the fix.

Comment: 0.23.1 saved the day!