# TypeError: Type aliases cannot be used with isinstance(), while using replace()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a code, which replace 'PO BOX" word from column under data frame. I am using python 3.7.2.

```
file = file["Address"].replace("PO BOX","")]
```

The above code will need to replace all the string value 'PO BOX' with ''. But while running this I got the below error, which I am not able to identify.

```
TypeError: Type aliases cannot be used with isinstance().
```

Comment: what's that bracket at the end? typo?

Comment: yes its typo :    file = file["Address"].replace("PO BOX","")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: Type aliases cannot be used with isinstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50495099/typeerror-type-aliases-cannot-be-used-with-isinstance). I realize your Python version is higher, but can you try updating pandas if it is an older version?